# Can we rewrite URLs in the same Apache Tomcat where we are hosting the application?

Tags: apache, tomcat, url-rewriting

I am hosting my Jenkins in a Tomcat 8.5.15 server. I want to rewrite the URL http://server.dns.com:8181/jenkins to https://mycompany.com/jenkins. Can I rewrite the URL in the same Tomcat or do I need to have another Tomcat in front of the one where I have hosted my Jenkins? Thanks a lot.

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand the problem. Do you know what DNS is? Do you want to just change the port from 8181 to 80?

Comment: In a machine abcd.xyz.mycompany, I have installed tomcat 8.5.15 at port 8181 and SSL port as 8182 and hosted jenkins in it. The resulting URL for Jenkins thus becomes http://abcd.xyz.mycompany:8181/Jenkins or https://abcd.xyz.mycompany:8182/Jenkins. Now, I want to expose a different URL to end users such as https://mycompany.xyz/jenkins which will internally resolve to https://abcd.xyz.mycompany:8182/Jenkins. Can I do this using rewrite rules in the same tomcat or do I need another one in front of this one.

Comment: Maybe i'm misunderstanding but couldn't you configure tomcat to use port 80 instead of 8182?

Comment: No. We are required not to use the default ports as dictated by policy.

Comment: But you are allowed to setup a different Tomcat server using a default port? Maybe i'm misunderstanding but a webbrowser will automatically use port 80 (or 443 for https requests) when you omit the port number in your url so you have to bind one of these ports.

Comment: @tobifasc...I understood now...you are right, I need to bind the default port first to a webserver i.e. a tomcat and then redirect to the required URL. I am new to middleware...still learning. Now, my question would be, can I bind the same tomcat which I used to setup using 80 default port with the required application url having different port.